# Regenerate user_nicename column

Tags: database, users

I'm struggling with a database issue. I took control over a solution created by someone else.

When inserting / updating users in the database, the earlier developers wrote a custom database script to update the `wp_users` table, and not through WordPress's API. They found out that they would use the `user_nicename` column for storing the first name of the user, and the `display_name` for storing the last name of the user. The names contains characters outside the english alphabet.

The script writes to these columns and we end up with a `user_nicename` like *Harald Åge*, which contains spaces and non-english characters. When using WordPress's API, it tries to make the `user_nicename` URL-friendly, but when using a database script to insert / update the user directly, WordPress won't have anything to say about this.

So now we have a partially corrupted database with non-URL-friendly `user_nicename`s.

My question is: Is there any way to regenerate these URL-friendly fields?

I guess it's possible to write a custom php-script which goes through all the users one by one and try to update the `user_nicename` value, or by letting WordPress handle that itself. Is there any other way of doing this?

And, in the future, we want to store the user's first name and last name in the `wp_usermeta` table instead, like WordPress does.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious method would be to write a custom WP-CLI script to run through the table, extract the first and last names, use `sanitize_title` to create a new nicename and update the record. You'd also need to copy the first and last names in wp_usermeta as you mention, at the same time.

I'm not sure I'm telling you anything you don't already know here.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I guess this is the simplest way (and maybe the only correct way) to do this.

Didn't know about `sanitize_title` though. That's exactly what I needed.

I want to add this though: some of the users in the table does already have their `user_nicename` correct, due to that they've not been updated yet. I think it's a better idea to get the first and last name through the CRM integration we have and update the database with the values from that.